# Folding bicycle on Iberia/Level - would I be charged as if I'm taking a normal bicycle?

Tags: luggage, bicycles, iberia

Iberia says they will charge US$75 to take a bicycle from BOS to BCN, but the text shows that they have not considered folding bicycles.

I wrote to them asking (providing weight and measurement) but they did not respond.

I pack my [Brompton](https://sep.yimg.com/ay/nycewheels/custom-brompton-folding-bike-builder-14.jpg) in a [Chubby](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/MLAEjkJ5-3Q/maxresdefault.jpg).  118 x 81 x 50¹ cm (47.2 x 32.4 x 20").  About 22 kilograms with both, but I like to fill up the corners with small items.

Anyone have experience with Iberia and a Brompton, or any other folding bicycle?

¹Height may vary but is close to 50 cm.  118 x 81 are accurate.

Comment: The sum of dimensions is still larger than their check-in maximum allowance (158 cm) so it has to go as a "bicycle" or "large/bulky item".

Answer (score 1):

99%, the rules for bicycles are for your regular, non-folding bicycle.  Folding bicycles, despite their recent popularity, are an edge case they haven't considered yet.

As for the case, there shouldn't be anything preventing you from checking it as an over sized item, for which you would have to pay.  However...I, me, personally, would not check the bike in a soft case, even if you tag it as Fragile.

There are hard shell cases for folding bikes.  Note, I do fully understand the dilemma of transporting a bike, then being stuck with a hard case. :(

Comment: The Chubby is not hard, but it is better than the T-bag that Brompton sells.  (Both are actually made by the same Dutch company.)  There is also a hard case that when empty, can itself be folded and put on the Brompton's rear rack.  But the Chubby doubles as a trailer.  As for paying for an oversize item, I understand that.  But some airlines waive the fee for a bicycle.  Anyway, I've already got my ticket, so I'llfind out what they do in March!